# Finding index number of a column in a csv file, but command doesnt show result?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, indexing, awk

I want to get the index number of a CSV column, depending on the column name.
For example I have these columns: `TotalReported;Deceased;City`
I tried doing this:

```
head -n1 data.csv | tr ";" "\n" | grep -nx "Deceased" | cut -d";" -f1
```

but nothing is being printed.
I also tried doing this:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="Deceased") {print i} exit}' data.csv'
```

which doesn't print anything.
What can I do?

This is the content of the `data.csv` file:

```
Date_of_report;Municipality_code;Municipality_name;Province;Total_reported;Hospital_admission;Deceased
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0003;Appingedam;Groningen;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0010;Delfzijl;Groningen;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0014;Groningen;Groningen;3;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0024;Loppersum;Groningen;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0034;Almere;Flevoland;1;1;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0037;Stadskanaal;Groningen;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0047;Veendam;Groningen;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0050;Zeewolde;Flevoland;1;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0059;Achtkarspelen;Friesland;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0060;Ameland;Friesland;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0072;Harlingen;Friesland;0;0;0
2020-03-13 10:00:00;GM0074;Heerenveen;Friesland;0;0;0
```

Basically I want to get the index number of a column, and then put the index number in this `awk` command

```
v1=$(awk -F";" '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv)
```

and get the sum of all the numbers of that specific column. The last three columns are important since you can only sum those of course.

Comment: What is the content of `data.csv` and what is the desired output?

Comment: Hi i edited my question, added the content of csv and desired output

Comment: What's the actual desired output?

Comment: The desired output is 7, because the index of column name "Deceased" is 7

Comment: Just leave off `| cut -d";" -f1` for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=";"
}
{ 
  gsub(/\r/,"")
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i=="Deceased"){
        print "Index is:"i
        exit
     }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

OR in case your string could be anything then you could create an `awk` variable named `strSearch` and could assign its value as per your string which you want to look for its index.

```
awk -v strSearch="Deceased" '
BEGIN{
  FS=";"
}
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i==strSearch){
        print "Index is:"i
        exit
     }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Index is:7
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `egrep -o` to get the start of the line and count the semicolon:

```
echo 'TotalReported;Deceased;City' | egrep -o '.*Deceased' | sed -e 's/[^;]//g' | wc -c
```

The output is `2` because Deceased is in the second column.

Comment: IMHO, with OP's given Input_file shouldn't it be `7` from first line of file?

Comment: Yes, he edited the question. Originally there was only the first example, but the solution also works for the first line of the .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

`echo  "Date_of_report;Municipality_code;Municipality_name;Province;Total_reported;Hospital_admission;Deceased" | awk -F';' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="Deceased") {print i} exit}'`

This prints '7'.
Note semicolon, not comma.

Comment: IMHO, with whole respect here, I think I have given same solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use @TheSlater version, it is more concise and better.

But as I was about to paste my shell script:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ];
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <file_name> <column_to_find>"
    exit 255
fi
I=1
FILE_NAME=$1
GOAL_COL=$2
head -1 $FILE_NAME > TMP
current_col=`cut -d";" -f$I TMP`
while [ ! -z $current_col ] && [ $current_col != $GOAL_COL ]
do
    ((I++))
    current_col=`cut -d";" -f$I TMP`
done

if [ -z $current_col ];
then 
    echo "NOTFOUND"
else
    echo "$I"
fi
rm TMP
exit 0
```

Just in case anyone finds it useful

EDIT:

```
$ sh findIndex.sh th.csv Deceased
7
```